# how to use the same method of jquery scrollTop with css3

Tags: jquery, css

I want the same effect scrollTop of jquery, but i wan't use it.
Because in some tablet this create problems (it not work with GPU).

Answer (score 5):

I recently solved this problem by transitioning on the `transform` property, then after the transition clearing the transform and setting `scrollTop`. That seems to work well.

```
document.body.style.webkitTransitionDuration="500ms";
document.body.style.webkitTransform="translate("+(left()-x)+"px,"+(top()-y)+"px)";
window.setTimeout(function(){
    document.body.style.webkitTransitionDuration="0ms";
    window.scrollTo(x,y);
},500);
```

and

```
body {                      
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1.8s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no CSS solution to this. However, would using hashes work for you, i.e. `http://example.com#footer` ? If so, just call the following line of JS:

```
window.location.hash = '#footer';
```

Comment: how can it help me to make the transition effect?

Comment: This won't work with a transition effect. Perhaps consider using it as a fallback for those specific devices/browsers that exhibit problems.

Comment: Ok thanks, but what it does in practice the method scrollTop (in the dom) ?
So I can understand how to find a solution and it would be very interesting!

Comment: Here's some useful documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollTop